# Conversion failed from string to datetime in SQL Server in Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am facing the problem to convert into datetime..

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Lastdate datetime
SET @Update = N'    
                        SELECT TOP 1 
                            '+@Lastdate+' = Purchase.LastUpdated
                        FROM    Purchase
                        WHERE   ID = 15                         
                    '
```

`LastUpdated` is also datetime format in database

Then why It cannot convert

> I want to set the datetime into declared variable @LastDate from purchase.lastupdate using sp_executesql only

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to set the date to declared variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another possible approach to set the value of `@LastUpdated` using `sp_executesql`:

```
-- Declaration
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @LastUpdated datetime
DECLARE @err int

-- Statement
SET @sql = N'
    SELECT TOP 1 @LastUpdated = Purchase.LastUpdated
    FROM Purchase
    WHERE ID = 15
'
-- Execution
EXEC @err = sp_executesql 
    @sql,
    N'@LastUpdated datetime OUTPUT',
    @LastUpdated OUTPUT

-- Test output
IF @err = 0 
   PRINT @LastUpdated
ELSE 
   PRINT 'Error'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass in a constant value, then use `sp_executesql`.  Your query doesn't really seem very useful.  This seems like a reasonable approximation:

```
DECLARE @LastUpdated datetime;
SET @Update = N'    
SELECT TOP 1 @LastUpdated as LastUpdated
FROM    Purchase
WHERE   ID = 15';

EXEC sp_executesql @Update,
                   N'@LastUpdated datetime',
                   @LastUpdated=@LastUpdated;
```

EDIT:

To update data, you need to use `UPDATE`.  But you don't need dynamic SQL:

```
UPDATE Purchase
    SET LastUpdated = @LastUpdated
    WHERE ID = 15;
```

If `ID` is not unique and you want to limit this to one (arbitrary) row:

```
UPDATE p
    SET LastUpdated = @LastUpdated
    FROM (SELECT TOP (1)
          FROM Purchase
         ) p
    WHERE ID = 15;
```

You should use an `ORDER BY` with `TOP` so you can control which row you are affecting.

Comment: I want to set the value of `Purchase.LastUpdated` to `@LastUpdated`